# ipyparallel installation: "ImportError: No module named paths"

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, enthought, canopy

After installing ipyparallel (OSX) via either Canopy package manager or pip, still can't import.

Note: A forum suggests easy_install path file inconsistencies. But I can't detect any line pointing to python site-packages folder in easy-install.pth.

```
/Users/tahahassan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py in <module>()

      11 
      12 from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
 ---> 13 from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
..

ImportError: No module named paths
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Canopy on OSX I have no difficulty in importing `ipyparallel`. Most likely is a confusion of ipython/jupyter-related package names and versions due to the change in package architecture with the change to jupyter. If you don't mind starting with a clean slate, I suggest uninstalling, resetting, and installing the current Canopy 1.6.2 ( see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website)).

If you don't want to do this because you've got lots of 3rd party packages installed, then I suggest doing a force install of jupyter and all dependencies, then of ipyparallel:

```
enpkg --forceall ipython
enpkg --forceall ipyparallel
```